# python -m grpc_tools.protoc uses experimental grpc APIs

Tags: python, grpc

When I use the following command

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. $proto_file
```

The generated grpc code uses experimental api

```
grpc.experimental.unary_unary
```

Is there a way to disable the use of experimental api?

Comment: See this [PR](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/22218#issuecomment-1092838208). There is no way to disable generation of code that includes references to `gprc.experimental`. IIUC, you need not use the class that is generated that uses the Experimental API. You can manually (!) `import grpc.experimental` to avoid import errors.

Comment: Thank you:) Guess I will not use this interface, but create the channel myself.